# SQL query not working with mssql - Dynaset (snapshot)

Tags: php, sql-server, database

I am querying a MSSQL server from my php website to return some information. When i run the query in access i get "#deleted" returned, but if i change the RecordSetType property to snapshot the result is produced.

How would I be able to change the recordsettype property in my php? I have done some research, but thus far i have yet to find any answers.

this is the query i am running:

```
$query = "SELECT dbo.VehicleJobHistory.BookingID,
dbo.VehicleJobHistory.TimeJobRequired  
FROM dbo.VehicleJobHistory 
WHERE dbo.VehicleJobHistory.BookingID = '30928512'  
ORDER BY dbo.VehicleJobHistory.BookingID";
```

Comment: why would you want to change recordset type in PHP, if its working for you, if not what the Error you get in PHP?

Comment: please run this query in phpmyadmin and check the result is it working fine?

Comment: @Praveenkalal this is MSSQL not MYSQL.